# SCSS file not including @used file's classes when imported in React component

Tags: reactjs, sass

I'm having an odd issue where I have two classes and a styling library (installed via npm) that aren't including properly.

The first file is my `main.scss`, and then I have a `page.scss` file that I use specifically in my `page.js` component, and a styling library. I also have `fonts.scss` and `variables.scss`

The top of my `main.scss` looks like this:

```
@charset "utf-8";
@use "~styling-library/styling-library";
@use "fonts";
@use "variables" as *;
```

This seems to be working fine, as my fonts and styling-library are being included correctly, *even on my page.js which doesn't directly reference it.*

I have this written art the top of `page.scss`:

```
@use "main";
@use "variables" as *;
```

I have this statement written at the top of `page.js:`

`import * as styles from '../styles/page.scss';`

And then I have a component, for example that looks like this:

`` <section className=`{styles.classFromLibrary} {styles.classFromMainStylesheet`> ``

Interestingly, `classFromLibrary` loads fine even though, as I stated before, it is not directly referenced from my `page.scss`. But `styles.classFromMainStylesheet` comes up undefined. Why would that be the case? Do I need to do something to make it so the classes in the main stylesheet are accessible?

Answer (score 1):

As is typical, I figured out what was wrong directly after answering. It turns out everything *is* imported, but the classnames are different than I assumed. I figured that it would automatically assume camel-case indicated something was hyphenated. Apparently not, and I have to figure out how to configure that manually.